# Write results from Kafka to csv in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka

I have setup a Kafka broker and I manage to read the records with pyspark.

```
import os
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark
import sys
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext, SQLContext, Row
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils

conf = SparkConf().setMaster("my-master").setAppName("Kafka_Spark")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sc.setLogLevel("WARN")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc,5)
kvs = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc,
                                        ['enriched_messages'], 
                                       {"metadata.broker.list":"my-kafka-broker","auto.offset.reset" : "smallest"},
                                        keyDecoder=lambda x: x,
                                        valueDecoder=lambda x: x)


lines  = kvs.map(lambda x: x[1])
lines.pprint()

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination(10)
```

Example of returning data (timestamp, name, lastname, height):

```
2020-05-07 09:16:38, JoHN, Doe, 182.5
```

I want to write these records into a csv file. `lines` is of type `KafkaTransformedDStream` and classic solution with rdd is not working.
Has anyone a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

converting DStreams to single rdd is not possible, as DStreams are continuous streams. You can use the following, which results many files, and later merge them to single file.

```
lines.saveAsTextFiles("prefix", "suffix")
```

Comment: I have some issues related to sqlContext. Where is the right place to import "from pyspark.shell import sqlContext"? Locally or globally?

Comment: I get a TypeError: 'KafkaTransformedDStream' object is not iterable when I import " from pyspark.shell import sqlContext"

Comment: Can you help me with this with an example? I am new to pyspark so it is a little bit confusing

Comment: Ok. this works but in termination the files is lost. is there a way to keep this locally?